# how to Automate the process of Checking twitter profile have option of sending message or not

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

i want to check list of certain profile whether it profile has message function or not[image: as there is inbox sign in this similarly i want to it is present or not]

so is it possible with selenium with the help python and requests

Answer (score 0):

You can just use try-else to find that element and get value based on this:

```
try:
    button = driver.find_element(...)
    send_button = 1
else:
    send_button = 0
```

You can expand this structure to a loop and store values in a nicer way like an array, column...

Be sure to carefully verify if the else statement triggers only when there is no button, e.g. by loading error.

Comment: @can you please do a sample as i don't get it
it'll be really if you do so